# Oracle dB - system table containing details of GUI to dB link

Tags: database, oracle, user-interface, metadata

I’m wondering if by default oracle dBs contain a system table which contains details which field on a GUI and how this maps to a dB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database 'sees' a bunch of sessions and statements, possibly with metadata saying what machine / program they relate to. Unless the GUI identifies itself in that metadata, the database doesn't know (and doesn't care) any more than that.

One exception is Oracle Apex where the web application actually runs from within the database. In that environment, there is an APEX view that relates database table/columns to items on the page in an application.

```
SELECT * FROM APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_DB_ITEMS
WHERE db_table_name = '....'
```

Comment: Thanks

I assume the logic, from what one may see on a GUI and where to fetch this data in the dB is maintained therefore within the code itself?

How would one go about in the absence of a well defined data dictionary established (especially for off the shelf software) how the application interface maps to the dB. 

Would PCF files be a good place to start especially with?